# What is the real world use or significance of sphinx doctest?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

What is is the significance of doctest in Sphinx? Can someone help me understand its use with a simple example.

Comment: Please clarify your question.  On the face of it, having documentation which shows usage also drive testing -- it seems naturally valuable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it myself but it is my understanding that it extends the functionality of `doctest`. For example it adds `testsetup` and `testcleanup` directives which you can put your set-up and tear-down logic in. Making it possible for Sphinx to exclude that in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Sphinx's doctest is for testing the documentation itself. In other words, it allows for the automatic verification of the documentation's sample code. While it might also verify whether the Python code works as expected, Sphinx is unnecessary for that purpose alone (you could more easily use the standard library's `doctest` module).

So, a real-world scenario (one I find myself in on a regular basis) goes something like this: a new feature is nearing completion, so I write some documentation to introduce the new feature. The new docs contain one or more code samples. Before publishing the documentation, I run `make doctest` in my Sphinx documentation directory to verify that the code samples I've written for the audience will actually work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example (from [the doctest module](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html#module-doctest)):

```
"""
This is the "example" module.

The example module supplies one function, factorial().  For example,

>>> factorial(5)
120
"""

def factorial(n):
    """Return the factorial of n, an exact integer >= 0.

    If the result is small enough to fit in an int, return an int.
    Else return a long.

    >>> [factorial(n) for n in range(6)]
    [1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120]
    >>> [factorial(long(n)) for n in range(6)]
    [1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120]
    >>> factorial(30)
    265252859812191058636308480000000L
    >>> factorial(30L)
    265252859812191058636308480000000L
    >>> factorial(-1)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    ValueError: n must be >= 0

    Factorials of floats are OK, but the float must be an exact integer:
    >>> factorial(30.1)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    ValueError: n must be exact integer
    >>> factorial(30.0)
    265252859812191058636308480000000L

    It must also not be ridiculously large:
    >>> factorial(1e100)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    OverflowError: n too large
    """

    import math
    if not n >= 0:
        raise ValueError("n must be >= 0")
    if math.floor(n) != n:
        raise ValueError("n must be exact integer")
    if n+1 == n:  # catch a value like 1e300
        raise OverflowError("n too large")
    result = 1
    factor = 2
    while factor <= n:
        result *= factor
        factor += 1
    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: I doesn't want the example. I want to understand its real world usage